# Non consistent example of topology

Tags: general-topology

I start with the set
$$
X=\{a,b,c,d\}
$$
and the subbasis
$$
\{\{\},\{a,b\},\{a,d\},\{b,c,d\},\{a,b,c,d\}\}
$$

The I generate the topology by first taking all possible (finite) intersections:
$$
\{\{\},\{a\},\{b\},\{a,b\},\{d\},\{a,d\},\{b,c,d\},\{a,b,c,d\}\}
$$
and then all union, obtaining the topology to the subbasis:
$$
\{\{\},\{a\},\{b\},\{a,b\},\{d\},\{a,d\},\{a,b,d\},\{b,c,d\},\{a,b,c,d\}\}
$$

The the closed set by taking all complements:
$$
\{\{\},\{a\},\{c\},\{b,c\},\{a,b,c\},\{c,d\},\{a,c,d\},\{b,c,d\},\{a,b,c,d\}\}
$$

Then I list all closures obtained by taking the intersection of all closed supersets of some given set:
$$
\text{cl}\{a\}=\{a\},\\
\text{cl}\{b\}=\{b,c\},\\
\text{cl}\{a,b\}=\{a,b,c\},\\
\text{cl}\{c\}=\{c\},\\
\text{cl}\{a,c\}=\{a,c\},\\
\text{cl}\{b,c\}=\{b,c\},\\
\text{cl}\{a,b,c\}=\{a,b,c\},\\
\text{cl}\{d\}=\{c,d\},\\
\text{cl}\{a,d\}=\{a,c,d\},\\
\text{cl}\{b,d\}=\{b,c,d\},\\
\text{cl}\{a,b,d\}=\{a,b,c,d\},\\
\text{cl}\{c,d\}=\{c,d\},\\
\text{cl}\{a,c,d\}=\{a,c,d\},\\
\text{cl}\{b,c,d\}=\{b,c,d\}
$$

> The problem is with the set $\{a,c\}$: (i) its complement is not open ($\{b,d\}$ is not in the topology); (ii) the closed super set of $\{a,c\}$ are $\{a,b,c\},\{a,c,d\},\{a,b,c,d\}$ whose intersection is $\{a,c\}$. That is, $\{a,c\}$ is not closed but
>   $$
> \text{cl}\{a,c\}=\{a,c\}
> $$
>   a contradiction.
>
> There must be an error. Where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The singletons $\{b\}$ and $\{d\}$ are in your collection of open sets, but you left out the set $\{b,d\}$. Its complement is $\{a,c\}$.